# Shell Variable Expansion in qsub command through drmaa

Tags: zsh, python, gridengine, qsub

I am running a bulk job submission to SGE (Sun Grid Engine) using [python drmaa bindings](https://github.com/pygridtools/drmaa-python).

For the bulk job submission I am submitting a python script that takes in one argument and is command line executable, through a shebang. To properly parameterize the job bulk submission I am setting environment variables to propagate to the python script through the `-v` option. I am trying to do an indirect variable expansion in my zsh environment based on the `$TASK_ID`/`$SGE_TASK_ID` environment variable that SGE exports during job submittal.

As a minimal reproducible example of the indirect variable expansion I am trying to do something like this, which works in my shell.

```bash
export foo1=2
export num=1

echo $(tmp=foo$num; echo ${(P)tmp})
```

which produces `2`

The example script `job_script.py`

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input_path", type=os.path.realpath)

def main(input_path):
    # do stuff
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args
    input_path = args.input_path
    main(input_path)
```

The example drmaa submittal script

```py
import os

# add path to libs
os.environ["DMRAA_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "path to DMRAA shared object"
os.environ["SGE_ROOT"] = "path to SGE root directory"
import drmaa

input_dir_suffixes = [1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11]

INPUT_BASE_DIR = "/home/mel/input_data"

base_qsub_options = {
    "P": "project",
    "q": "queue",
    "b": "y", # means is an executable
    "shell": "y", # start up shell
}
native_specification = " ".join(f"-{k} {v}" for k,v in base_qsub_options.items())
remote_command = "job_script.py"

num_task_ids = len(input_dir_suffixes)
task_start = 1
task_stop = num_task_ids + 1
task_step = 1
task_id_zip = zip(range(1, num_task_ids + 1), input_dir_suffixes) 
task_id_env_vars = {
   f"TASK_ID_{task_id}_SUFFIX": str(suffix) for task_id, suffix in task_id_zip 
}

io_task_id = r"$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID_$TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp)})"
arg_task_id = r"$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID_$SGE_TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp)})"

with drmaa.Session() as session:
    
    template = session.createJobTemplate()
    template.nativeSpecification = native_specification
    template.remoteCommand = remote_command
    template.jobEnvironment = task_id_env_vars
    template.outputPath = f":{INPUT_BASE_DIR}/output/{io_task_id}.o"
    template.outputPath = f":{INPUT_BASE_DIR}/error/{io_task_id}.e"

    args_list = [f"{INPUT_BASE_DIR}/data{arg_task_id}"]
    template.args = args_list
    session.runBulkJobs(template, task_start, task_stop - 1, task_step)
    session.deleteJobTemplate(template)
```

Apologize if there is a syntax error, I have to hand copy this, as its on a different system.

With the submission done

If I do a `qstat -j` on the job number

I get the following settings displayed

```
sge_o_shell:         /usr/bin/zsh
stderr_path_list:    NONE:<node>:/home/mel/input_data/error_log/$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID_$TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp}).e
stdout_path_list:    NONE:<node>:/home/mel/input_data/output_log/$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID_$TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp}).o
job_args:            /home/mel/input_data/data$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID$SGE_TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp})
script_file:         job_script.py

env_list: 
SUFFIX_TASK_ID_1=1,SUFFIX_TASK_ID_2=2,SUFFIX_TASK_ID_3=5,SUFFIX_TASK_ID_4=7,SUFFIX_TASK_ID_5=10,SUFFIX_TASK_ID_6=11
```

error logs and output logs get made respectively but there is only a partial expansion.

Examples

```
$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID1; echo ${(P)tmp}).e
$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID1; echo ${(P)tmp}).o
```

If we `cat` the error logs we see `Illegal variable name`

Is what I am trying to do possible?

So I am presuming something somewhere is not activating my zsh correctly.

Comment: Not familiar with the system, but the symptoms look like the _submitting_ shell is `sh` (or at least not Zsh), even though it allows you to run jobs using any shell you like.

Answer (score 1):

SGE uses Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) as its default shell for job scripts, which can lead to issues with scripts that rely on features or syntax specific to other shells. In your case, you're trying to use a `zsh` feature (parameter expansion with `${(P)tmp}`).

The issue seems to be with the shell variable expansion that you're trying to perform within your DRMAA job. It looks like your indirect variable expansion (`${(P)tmp}`) is not being recognized correctly when the job is submitted to SGE.

What sticks out here is that while your login shell might be `zsh` (`sge_o_shell: /usr/bin/zsh`), the shell that *interprets* the qsub command line arguments and the DRMAA job submission parameters might not be `zsh`. The `${(P)tmp}` syntax is specific to `zsh`, and will not work in other shells such as `bash` or `sh`, which could be the shell that's interpreting these parameters.

So, when you submit the job with the `-v` option (passing environment variables) and with command substitution (`$(...)`) in your DRMAA script, SGE might not be interpreting these parts of the command using `zsh`, which is why the `zsh`-specific syntax doesn't work.

This means that you might have to create a wrapper script which uses `zsh` to perform the variable expansion and then call your Python script with the results. This wrapper script would be submitted as the job script, and it could use `zsh`'s features because you're running it through `zsh`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# use zsh for variable expansion
suffix=$(tmp=SUFFIX_TASK_ID_$TASK_ID; echo ${(P)tmp})

# call the python script with the result(s)
exec /path/to/job_script.py /home/mel/input_data/data$suffix
```

Submit the wrapper script as the job in your DRMAA script and specify that it should be run with `zsh`:

```py
...
# path to the wrapper script
remote_command = "/path/to/wrapper_script.zsh"

...
# specify that the job should be run with zsh
base_qsub_options = {
    ...
    "shell": "/usr/bin/zsh",
    ...
}
...
```

**NB:** you might have to adjust these based on your needs.

Comment: Going to test out a change with it as `sh`. Where did you find out that the submitting shell is `sh`?